# Detox gets stuck on JS Timer/Main Run Loop when registering a lot of screens with React Native Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, e2e-testing, react-native-navigation, detox

I have a React Native app that is using React Native Navigation, and this app registers a lot of screens with RNN at bootup (83 screens, to be precise). When I try to run a Detox E2E test against the app, Detox reports that the system is busy:

```
detox[1831] INFO:  [APP_STATUS] The system is busy with the following tasks:

Dispatch Queue
⏱ Queue: “Main Queue (<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread>)” with 1 work item

JS Timer
⏱ 3536

Run Loop
⏱ “Main Run Loop”
```

One thing I've found that prevents this is when I comment out most of the RNN screen registration calls, leaving only the essential screens to run the tests. When I do that, the Detox tests run just fine. What also helped was to switch all of the `import` calls for the RNN screens being registered to inline `require`s. But this loses us our type checking for all of those screen components. I have tried using `Navigation.setLazyComponentRegistrator()` and I still get the Detox timeouts.

I've been all over the app looking for stray JS timers or animations, to see if there's something I'm missing that the RNN registration calls are just exacerbating. But I'm at a loss at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being caused by a JS timer initiated at load by d3-timer, which was being included as part of Victory Native. https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native/issues/588

Comment: stumbled in this issue too, so as a tip for anyone trying to find out where someone may have registered a interval or timeout, you can simply put a `setTimeout = null` or `setInterval = null` in the code (in the right place) and see the stack trace of someone else code calling it. this is how I found where the timer was being set